# Javascript new class/type that extends from a DOM class/type

Tags: javascript, dom, extend

I did some googling on extending a DOM class, and I mostly see:
-add your own functions to Element.prototype (or some more specific Element)
-attachment your own functions to each instance of your object on each object creation
-wrap the DOM element with a regular object

I have come up with the following way of extending DOM, and seem to work exactly the way I want after I tested it (but only simple tests).

```
function X() { //my class X extending HTMLDivElement
    //skipping 'this', creating my own object instead and setting the prototype to X myself
    let x=document.createElement('div');
    Object.setPrototypeOf(x, X.prototype);
    return x;
}
X.prototype=Object.create(HTMLDivElement.prototype);
X.prototype.m1=function() { console.log('method m1 from X!!!'); };

let x=new X();
document.body.appendChild(x);

x.m1();

function XX() { //my class XX extending X
    //skipping 'this' also, creating my own object from X instead, and chainning the prototype XX
    //the prototype chainning is now HTMLDivElement -> X -> XX
    let xx=new X();
    Object.setPrototypeOf(xx, XX.prototype);
    return xx;
}
XX.prototype=Object.create(X.prototype);
XX.prototype.m1=function() { console.log('method m1 from XX!!!'); };

let xx=new XX();
document.body.appendChild(xx);
xx.m1();

console.log("x instanceof HTMLDivElement?" + (x instanceof HTMLDivElement)); //true
console.log("x instanceof X?" + (x instanceof X)); //true
console.log("x instanceof XX?" + (x instanceof XX)); //false
console.log("xx instanceof HTMLDivElement?" + (xx instanceof HTMLDivElement)); //true
console.log("xx instanceof X?" + (xx instanceof X)); //true
console.log("xx instanceof XX?" + (xx instanceof XX)); //true
```

I created 100,000 such object and put them inside document.body, and it seems to perform similar to using plain div's.

Is there anything wrong with this? / Has anyone done something like this?
I have read about and understand issues in using setPrototypeOf.

Comment: This will not work for any element with 'magic' properties, SELECT, BUTTON, etc...nor is it at all clear why you're doing this...especially in a world that already has custom elements...https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If the solution/method/answer I presented here is a valid one, I thought that would be beneficial to other SO visitors.  This is not an uncommon question, and I don't see a clear winner answer from any website. (Not that I see mine as a winner, but at least something for others to consider.)